# Why does Anaconda Prompt show my python version and Command Prompt does not?

Tags: python, command-line, pip, anaconda

I am trying to completely uninstall python and pip from my machine. The reason being is
due to the recent pip version 22.0, I have been unable to add or remove modules. I have tried reverting to a previous versions of pip, but to no avail. My Anaconda Prompt errors. Therefore, I decided to reinstall python and pip on my machine.

I uninstalled Python 3.7.9 under Windows "Add or Remove Programs", and no versions of python are found in my Command Prompt. **If python is uninstalled why does it show versions with my Anaconda Prompt?**

Also, if you have any remedies to the issue with pip 22.0, that would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure if my solution of uninstalling python & pip is correct.

Pip 22.0 Error I was referring too.
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-267507

See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to Stack Overflow!

From what I can see, Anaconda installs its own version of Python which exists separately from any other version of Python that you may have manually installed.

For your original pip problem, you could try a clean installation of Anaconda? If that fails, then I would recommend creating a new SO question to get help for that as a separate issue (I'd also suggest summarising the v22 issue, since the link provided requires you to sign up for a JFrog account)

Comment: Thanks! I expect I will be on here all the time now. 

I ended up resolving the original pip problem by uninstalling pip and python. It just took a long time. 

I was able to get both the Anaconda Prompt and CMD working again by changing the system variable names. However, I'm still confused why the versions are different despite them referencing the same path. You said Anaconda installs it's own version of python? Any ideas? See attached image.


https://imgur.com/a/BZTie9P

Comment: I'm glad you were able to resolve one issue at least. Since you plan to be around, I recommend reading the following Help pages on how to ask good questions, as if you can include the recommended information then it will help people help you more efficiently. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you look at that screenshot, the Anaconda prompt is actually showing two paths after you run "where python". The first path is the Anaconda installation of Python (which will be 3.7.3) and the second path is a manual installation of Python (3.7.9). 

I installed Anaconda to test, and by default, the path to Anaconda's Python.exe isn't added to the PATH environment variable, which is why it doesn't show up in the bottom command prompt. However, when you run the Ananconda prompt, the path to the Anaconda Python.exe is set for that prompt only. Does that make sense?

Comment: I read the "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" page the other day. What did I say that you didn't like?

Comment: I actually don't know if I solved my issues with pip. It's possible I created more problems. I do see the directory you are referring to in the image I linked. I was unsure why two are listed. Is Anaconda showing both directories a problem? If it is a problem, what issues does this cause and how do I fix it?

Comment: First off, a question on SO should relate to a single issue (eg: "If python is uninstalled why does it show versions with my Anaconda Prompt?"). However, you also asked about the pip issue at the same time. It's not a big problem in this instance, but it can lead to negative comments and questions being downvoted. 

Second, having two directories listed is not a problem provided you remember that you actually have two Python installations on your computer which may be different versions and thus behave differently with your scripts. That's all.